# In MVC, is it okay to store regex patterns and do validation checks in the view?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have my regex patterns stored like:

```
private final Pattern regex1...
private final Pattern regex2...
```

As fields in my view. I have a validation check method in the view class which throws an exception to the controller when validation fails. Is this valid in MVC or not?

```
public void validation() throws Exception{

    if(regex failed){
        throw new exception("...");
    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always somehow up to you how you splitt the code, if there is a good reason behind your decision.

However, I would prefer to put the validation methode at **least** into the controller, because it looks like it will be triggered by an actionevent from a button. (Events should be handled in the controller)

What you can do, is to create a methode in your view, which shows an error message in the gui, if your validation has failed.

All this implice that also the regex is saved in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice. Logic has to be moved into dedicated layed.
Best way is creating dedicated validator class OR create validation method of a service (if some operations like search in DB have to be done during the validation). In that way validator class can be well covered by unit tests.

@Autowire
UserInputValidator userInputValidator;

public void validation() throws Exception{

```
if(userInputValidator.validate(param1, param2)){
    throw new exception("...");
}
...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

While we're talking about MVC, it's always best to consider that as the app evolves, "input" may come from more than one place eventually.

- User
- service call
- file
- other

In this case we wouldn't want to build the validation mechanisms into the View or the Controller, but into another component that the Controller would just use/integrate with.

## Validation can be a cross cutting concern (but not always)

Ideally we would want to avoid duplicating the validation of incoming data especially if the data is always valid in the same way. Duplicating the validation can cause inconsistencies. Imagine data being invalid from the UI, but the same data being considered "ok" from a service call.

There are a number of ways that you can separate the validation logic from your view:

- Annotate beans for [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)

  - Create custom validation annotations (abstracting your defined regex's) and/or use libraries that provide some [basic ones](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)
- Dedicated service

## Resolving validation failures

I can see that you're throwing an exception when you have a validation failure. Consider the awesome article by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html). The suggestion is that a validation failure can be expected and is not an `Exception` case. He also suggests a notification approach.

Another advantage of a notification approach is that your dedicated validation service/tier can support multiple validation failures. This would allow your view to highlight multiple fields or your API to return a list of failures.